# Python 2.7 - Regex - How to find some characters X in some pieces of string Y that are found between two characters Z1 and Z2 inside a big string S?

Tags: regex, python-2.7

in relation to the title, if:

```
S = "\sasdf2ad  sf\s29 [  9,  ve\s , 45, fd  ] lak  [l23l] jk4\s [[5 ,3 \s],\s fgt]   asdldl"
```

does a regex exist to find only the character "\s" (several times) inside "[" and "]"?

In other words, I need to find only the bolded "**\s**":

```
S = "\sasdf2ad  sf\s29 [  9,  ve**\s** , 45, fd  ] lak  [l23l] jk4\s [[5 ,3 **\s**],**\s** fgt]   asdldl"
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the linked solution, you just need to replace round brackets with square ones.

Comment: Sorry, how can I set bolded strings in code? In my question I see ** \s **. Thanks!

Comment: `\s` is whitespace. To remove whitespace, you may just use `''.join(x.group(0).split())`, no regex is necessary. Well, you may just use a regex replacement - `re.sub(r'\s+', '', x.group(0))`

Comment: Hi Wiktor, sorry but the regex "\\[.*?\\]" matches "[ 9, ve\s , 45, fd ]", "[l23l]" and "[[5 ,3 \s]". I need only "\s" as a character (no whitespace special character) only inside any "[" and "]". Thanks

Comment: To match a 2-char substring `r'\s'` you need to use a `r'\\s'` regex pattern. But if you need to literally replace it, use `.replace(r'\s', '')`. Right, `"\[.*?]"` matches those substrings, but inside the lambda expression, you may manipulate the match. See the linked solution.

Comment: Another idea is [`r'\\s(?=[^][]*])'`](https://regex101.com/r/BBnrrB/1)

Comment: Ok, I try... and your solution "\\s(?=[^][]*])" works very well! one thing: I'm new in stackoverflow, can you please tell me how to bold any text in code?

Comment: It is not possible. Note the `r'\\s(?=[^][]*])'` is a *work around*. Using lambda inside `re.sub` is the *solution*. I believe you need to replace that `\s`.

Comment: Ok, thank you Wiktor!

Comment: I am sure there is a better dupe, but I can't find it right now.